# print object value from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I need to read rss feed and then re-create feeds as it is.
If there is 10 item I just need 3. But I want to define which one. first 3 or last 3 or middle. After this I need to show only 3 item in feed. But feed most as it was previous one. Only my purpose is to split Feed.
Here what I'm using but it's not working.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0">';

$url_number = $_GET['u'];
$offset = $_GET['o'];
$limit = $_GET['l'];


$url = 'url_of_the_feed';

$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo "<channel>". (string) $feed->channel. "</channel>";

$i = 1;

foreach($feed->channel->item as $item){

    if($i >= $offset && $i <= $limit){
        echo "<item>" . $item . "</item>";
    }

    if($i == $limit){
        break;
    }

    $i++;

}

echo "</channel></rss>";

?>
```

This is not printing anything inside channel and item.

Comment: put all the `channel` nodes into an array and use `array_chunk` when you need to select which to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you output the XML, your just echoing out the SimpleXMLElement object (`$item`), which will not give you anything useful.  You need to output the element in XML format.

```
    echo "<item>" . $item->asXML() . "</item>";
```

It would be better to manipulate the document directly using SimpleXML, but this should solve your immediate problem.

This enables you to just remove the items you don't want, it also has the benefit of retaining any other data which is in the original document. 
  It loops through the item elements and uses `unset` to remove the ones out of the range you want...

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$url_number = $_GET['u'];
$offset = $_GET['o'];
$limit = $_GET['l'];

$url = 'url_of_the_feed';

$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
$removed = 0;
$itemCount = count($feed->channel->item);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $itemCount ; $i++ )  {
    if($i < $offset || $i > $limit){
        unset ($feed->channel->item[$i - $removed]);
        $removed++;
    }
}    
echo $feed->asXML();
```

Updated - as per comments, the code was removing items from the array, but not adjusting itself accordingly.  The code now keeps track of the number of items removed and therefore where `$i` is relative to the current array contents.

Comment: There is little problem in your code. You are counting feed item in for loop after unset any feed it effect on `count` you need to create first variable `$feedCount = count($feed->channel->item)`  and use in loop

Comment: Yes @AzeemHaider you are right

Comment: @AzeemHaider, thanks for that, it was slightly more than that but I've updated the code.  Next time I will just stick to answering the question asked.